# Audio manipulation - How to

Tags: midi, keyboard, voice-manipulation

I've always wanted to learn on how to manipulate voice/audio.

For example here we have a video that basically the meows of the cats were changed into the notes of a song, to understand this you should know about the Despacito song.

1. 

I watched another series of videos which the normal conversation of a game character was converted into a song, but to understand this you should have played the GTA San Andreas Game, or at least know about the popular OHHHHH of Big Smoke.

1. 
2. 
3. 

There are a lot of videos like this, I know it has something to do with an audio editing software like Adobe Audition and probably using Keyboard/Midi plugins, but I don't know where to start and what to search for, please put me in the direction for tutorials (even paid) to learn on doing these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to search for tutorials on "Audio Sampling", "Audio Pitch Manipulation", "Audio Editing" and "Video Editing". You will need to learn how to use a Digital Audio Workstation such as "Reaper" or "Pro-Tools".

If you are starting from scratch, it's a long road ahead of you, but rewarding as you make the journey.